# UseDatabaseNullSemantics not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, null

this is the query I am trying to execute:

```
int? i = default(int);
   var orders= db.orders.Include(p => p.regions).Include(p => p.types);
        int? i = default(int);
        var list = orders
            .Where(item => item.visible== true && ( (item.children== true) || ((item.dad== i) && item.children== false) )).OrderByDescending(item => item.year);
```

db is a IdentityDbContext; in its constructor I set
    this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;

The generated query is the following:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[id] AS [id], 

[Project1].[visible] AS [visible], 
[Project1].[dad] AS [dad], 
[Project1].[children] AS [children], 

FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 

    [Extent1].[visible] AS [visible], 
    [Extent1].[dad] AS [dad], 
    [Extent1].[children] AS [children], 
    [Extent1].[n_unita] AS [n_unita]
    FROM [dbo].[orders] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[visible]) AND ((1 = [Extent1].[children]) OR (([Extent1].[dad] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = [Extent1].[children])))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[year] DESC
```

The problem is that with item.dad want to check also if dad is NULL, but this is not happening and I cannot understand why, where am I mistaken?

Nothing changes with this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = false;

Answer (score 0):

This answer gave me the solution: [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970039/4334348).
There is nothing wrong with this code, a change had to be made in the class extending IdentityDbContext in order to make ef generate the correct IS NULL check.

Dad field is a foreign key and I made the mistake to tell the code that is a required field, while it is not, so I corrected the code in the following way:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<orders>()
            .HasMany(e => e.order)
            .WithOptional(e => e.dad_orders)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.dad)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```